# Subprocess wait expect script to finish

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm calling the subprocess (expect script to run some command) and need to wait until it is finished to start another function, but with this I think it only wait until shell command is finihed, and not the expect script.
Is it possible to wait for the whole process to finish?

```
 p111 = subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal -e "perl /tmp/expect',shell=True)  
    os.waitpid(p111.pid,0)
    smo_final()
```

Comment: Why do you need gnome-terminal?

Comment: to start expect script in new window, to show user all the process what is done by expect script. This is just part of GUI program.

Comment: `shell=True`  is not recommended

Comment: Normally you would read stdout and stderr of your subprocess and place it in your GUI wherever you want.

Comment: `os.waitpid` is designed to be used with `os.fork`, you should use `p111.wait()`.  That's not the cause of your problem though, not using a shell might resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

```
  p11 = subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal -e "perl /tmp/expect',shell=False)  
  p11.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pexpect, a python expect [implementation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
import pexpect
...
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd) # the command you want to run
child.expect(str_expect) # the string you expect 
child.sendline(str_response) # the string with which you'd like to respond 
child.wait() # wait for the child to exit
...
# the rest of your code here
```

Comment: yes this is correct, but in y case I have to call expect script for some other reasons...